# Calculate Sample variance of a dataset using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have simple data: `1,2,3,4,5`

I want to calculate sample variance using numpy, but `numpy.var([1,2,3,4,5])`, gives population variance.

Can any one plz help in how to get sample variance.

Answer (score 7):

From https://machinelearningmastery.com/introduction-to-expected-value-variance-and-covariance/:

> In NumPy, the variance can be calculated for a vector or a matrix
>   using the var() function. By default, the var() function calculates
>   the population variance. To calculate the sample variance, you must
>   set the `ddof` argument to the value 1.

Comment: Also check the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.var.html) explanation for the argument `ddof`.